# How to specify data generated recently only in lucene?

Tags: lucene, kibana

I'm newbie for ELK and now wondering how to specify recent data only using lucene query in Kibana.

I'm trying to do like:
timestamp:[10 minutes ago TO now]

I found the way to specify static range of time window, but I would like to show a dynamic graph based on recent data only.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Answer myself..

I found this post. Right now kibana doesn't support such query.

https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/4278